# How does the AsyncTask work if you wanna write a file?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

First of all sorry for my english, and secodly i'm new in Android & Java and so don't judge me.

I can read the JSON file from the Get request that i'm doing, but 
I want to write the response that I'll get in a file somewhere in internal memory's device. I don't know how to do with the Async Task because i'm having the error that has been shown down..Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?!

```
08-05 15:06:14.305    3302-3317/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: shapp.odk.org.shapp, PID: 3302
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at shapp.odk.org.shapp.RequestHandlerApi.doInBackground(RequestHandlerApi.java:58)
        at shapp.odk.org.shapp.RequestHandlerApi.doInBackground(RequestHandlerApi.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks in advance :)!

```
class RequestHandlerApi extends AsyncTask<String,String, String>{

    private Context contextMain;



   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

    try{
        URL urlHarassmentApi = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:5000/geo-api");
        HttpURLConnection connMain = (HttpURLConnection)urlHarassmentApi.openConnection();
        connMain.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connMain.setRequestMethod("GET");
        Log.d("Hello",""+connMain);

        /*
        if (connMain.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + connMain.getResponseCode());
        }*/

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connMain.getInputStream()));


        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);

        }


        reader.close();



            try {
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(contextMain.openFileOutput("config.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                outputStreamWriter.write(response.toString());
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: @nhaarman thanks that you edited my post (y)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well your **contextMain is null** what you can do is to create a constructor and pass the activity context to it and then use it

change your calling to

```
 new RequestHandlerApi(Your_Activty_Name.this).execute("your url here");
```

then in your RequestHandlerApi  class create a constructor

hen Create a Constructor and also create a variable Context context;

```
 public RequestHandlerApi(Context context){
   this.contextMain =context;
}
```

now your contextMain is not null.

Comment: passing the Activity context to a Background thread is a sure way of getting a memory leak.

Comment: @Budius and how can I avoid this memory leak?

Comment: First to begin with, there's no real reason for you to use an AsyncTask. You could use an `IntentService` as AsyncTask was made to give feedback to the UI, something you're not doing. And then you could use the Service context without issues. But to simple "fix" your current code the best would be to get application context instead `this.contextMain = context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Budius aha, okay I understood. Thanks for the suggestion!